# Transpose Boolean Columns to Header Names (Google Sheets to BigQuery SQL)

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that currently includes the following columns:

- event_date
- event_id
- studio_1
- studio_2

event_date is a date type, event_id an integer, and studio_1 & studio_2 are both TRUE/FALSE (checkbox in Sheets) Example schema:

| event_date | event_id | studio_1 | studio_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-15 | 1234 | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2024-03-16 | 5678 | TRUE | TRUE |

I want to transpose these values to stack the studio_1 & studio_2 columns on top of one another, and rather than TRUE, call out the name of the studio that is booked in a new column called studio_booked. How I want it to look:

| event_date | event_id | studio_booked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-15 | 1234 | Studio 1 |
| 2024-03-16 | 5678 | Studio 1 |
| 2024-03-16 | 5678 | Studio 2 |

Basically I want to generate a single column noting the studio that is booked with duplication of the date and event_id columns so I can count total bookings in each studio per date/event_id while also being able to filter on the space name in a single column rather than needing to fitler on each studio's column where TRUE.

This data is intened to be loaded into a dashboard via SQL script in which the current database schema matches the above schema. Are there any combinations of functions/formulas that can be used to transform the data in Sheets before being uploaded? Would also appreciate guidance on writing a SQL statement to handle the transformation in BigQuery instead.

Comment: Most of this question is written very well. You make very clear how your want your Google Sheet data to be transformed and why. The examples you show help a lot. Please edit the bottom part of your question. You provide two alternative approaches and ask which one is best, which is a matter of opinion or taste. You might rewrite to ask help on how to do the data transformation in Google Sheets. You might also ask help to write an SQL statement to do the transformation in BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, @MartijnDirkse! Just edited the bottom part of the question based on your suggestions; please feel free to let me know if you think further edits would be more helpful for the question.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have upvoted your question.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a shorter solution, but here is a GoogleSQL script that does the job. With `UNION`, you can concatenate rows (vertically):

```sql
SELECT event_date, event_id, 'Studio 1' AS studio_booked
FROM spreadsheet
WHERE studio_1 IS TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT event_date, event_id, 'Studio 2' AS studio_booked
FROM spreadsheet
WHERE studio_2 IS TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (for BigQuery) approach

```
select * except(booked)
from your_table
unpivot(booked for studio_booked in (studio_1, studio_2))
where booked
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]